# How to resign/ change bundle id for an already built APK in an Azure Devops release pipeline

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working with a client who wants to deploy multiple versions of their android application (representing DEV, TEST, UAT, PROD, etc) to the same device.

Normally, with any application, I'd prefer to promote the same compiled binary code from one environment to the next. For example, if a build passed testing in TEST, I'd like to promote that exact build (perhaps with different configs) to UAT. This would be possible if the clients test environments were different devices, but given they have the same android device running multiple versions of the app, I'm wondering if there's any kind of best practice here.

The client is using Azure DevOps. Is there an easy way to build the APK as part of an Azure build pipeline, and then change its Bundle Id, or google-services.json in a release pipeline to indicate that it's a "Dev" or "QA" version of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use extension '[Mobile App Tasks for iOS and Android](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks&ssr=false#overview)', this extension includes tasks to change app's version name and code or app's package name at build/release time. If the extension can not satisfy your requirement, you can refer the [source code](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/vsts-mobile-tasks), modify it and create a custom extension. Please see [how to create a custom pipleline task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fextend%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fextend%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops).